# Pandas find the mean of DataFrame based on a conditional across multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find the average weight of females under 20, I have the following DataFrame, I have already converted age to int and weight to float.

```
 age   weight     height   male
 39.0   88.636360   180.0   True
 64.0   75.000000   155.0  False
 17.0  100.000000   183.0  False
 35.0   63.636364   170.0  True
 18.0   70.454544   173.0  False
```

I've tried `df.groupby(['male','age'])['weight'].mean()[False]` but it just returns something like:

```
age    
18.0    64.225121
19.0    65.499535
20.0    67.855026
21.0    69.622658
22.0    69.376862
```

How can I filter it so that it aggregates the weight of all female under 20 then takes the average?

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for groupby unless I'm misunderstanding. You can filter the dataframe based on your conditions then take the mean of the weight column.

```py
df.loc[(~df["male"]) & (df["age"] < 20), "weight"].mean()
```

Comment: Ah thanks that worked thanks!, no worries you did not misunderstand .